# Saving a barplot in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib

I have two python lists - a (entries are strings) and b (numerical). I plot them with the following snippet (works perfectly) -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(names, values)
plt.suptitle('Average Resale Price (SGD) vs Flat Model')
plt.xticks(rotation='82.5')
plt.show()
```

Now I try to save the above figure -

```
plt.savefig('foo.png',dpi=400)
```

However I end up getting a white figure! How do I save the barplot ?

Comment: What else have you tried? Why do you expect this to work and it does not?

Comment: The python code halts when you call `plt.show()`, so I'm guessing that you are closing the figure before `plt.savefig` is being called -- it might be that this is the reason for the white figure. Try to comment out the `plt.show()` line and re-run the code.

Comment: Thomas Kuhn, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

It's not hard. Try to put `plt.savefig('foo.png',dpi=400)` before `plt.show()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names=['alex', 'simon', 'beta']
values=[10,20,30]

plt.bar(names, values)

plt.suptitle('Average Resale Price (SGD) vs Flat Model')
plt.xticks(rotation='82.5')

plt.savefig('foo.png',dpi=400)
plt.show()
```

[image]